# Angular 11 Bootstrap 4.6.0. Styling/Accordion not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to "Re-teach" myself some basics of angular.  I am however having trouble with a basic element of bootstrap.  The Accordian in bootstrap to be specific.  I cannot get it to style, or work at all for that matter.  I believe I am missing something basic, as I have not really been active with the WebDev world, I may have just forgot.  Any help would be appreciated.

Below are the files.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.9.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.3"
```

},

angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

I copied the accordion example directly from the bootstrap website

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors. however I discovered I was using an example from bootstrap 5, and had only installed 4.6

Answer (score 0):

When I posted this I saw my problem, The example given is using Bootstrap 5, however I had installed Bootstrap 4.6.